# trying to set font using ttf ,working in activity xml but not in fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to set fontfamily of all my textView in an activity in follwing and its working in my activity xml part but the textViews in fragments remain unchanged
  // calling from oncreate method of activity

```
 overrideFonts(this,getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));

// function
    private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
        try {
            if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
                for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    overrideFonts(context, child);
             }
            } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Pacifico.ttf"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
     }
     }
```

Comment: where you are calling `overrideFonts` in Fragment?

Comment: inside onCreate method

Comment: because `onCreate` of Fragment called before `onCreateView` so probably code is not working. try it inside `onCreateView` or in `onViewCreated`

Comment: copied the code to onCreateView of each fragment but did no change also copied the code to onStrat() method of main activity which loaded font nicely at first but upon clicking any link or button font change lost

Comment: You probably shouldn't use android.R.id.content with fragments. Just place id for your main view (e.g. android:id="@+id/root") and then use just overrideFonts(findViewById(R.id.root)). BTW, your idea is great, I appreciate it.

Comment: @cyanide thank you, already tried that with no results